# Castle Windsor with Azure Functions (v3)

Tags: dependency-injection, azure-functions, castle-windsor

I'm going around in circles with this. Is there any way to use the Castle Windsor dependency injection adapter (https://github.com/volosoft/castle-windsor-ms-adapter) with Azure Function apps?

The code example on the adaptor github page is for ASP.NET Core but I would have imagined that there'd be a way to specify the service provider used for a function app, too?

Answer (score 0):

There have been no official documents on this but there is a feature request made by [DavidJFowler](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/4410)

Please find the sample code from the above feature request.

**The  `IJobActivatorEx`  implementation:**

```
    public class CastleWindsorJobActivator : IJobActivatorEx
    {
        private readonly WindsorContainer container;

        public CastleWindsorJobActivator(WindsorContainer container) => this.container = container;

        public T CreateInstance<T>(IFunctionInstanceEx functionInstance)
        {
            var disposer = functionInstance.InstanceServices.GetRequiredService<ScopeDisposable>();
            disposer.Scope = container.BeginScope();
            return container.Resolve<T>();
        }

        // Ensures a created Castle.Windsor scope is disposed at the end of the request
        public sealed class ScopeDisposable : IDisposable
        {
            public IDisposable Scope { get; set; }
            public void Dispose() => this.Scope?.Dispose();
        }

        public T CreateInstance<T>()
        {
            var disposer = container.Resolve<ScopeDisposable>();
            disposer.Scope = container.BeginScope();
            return container.Resolve<T>();
        }
    }
```

---

**Startup class:**

```
[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(FunctionApp2.Startup))]
namespace FunctionApp2
{
    public class Startup: FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            var container = new WindsorContainer();

           container.Register(Component.For<IScoped1>().ImplementedBy<Scoped1>().LifestyleScoped())
                .Register(Component.For<IScoped2>().ImplementedBy<Scoped2>().LifestyleScoped())
                .Register(Component.For<ISingleton1>().ImplementedBy<Singleton1>())
                .Register(Component.For<ISingleton2>().ImplementedBy<Singleton2>());

            // register function classes in container
            var functions = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(t =>
                t.GetMethods().Any(m => m.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(FunctionNameAttribute), false).Any()));

            foreach (var function in functions)
            {
                container.Register(Component.For(function).LifestyleScoped());
            }

            builder.Services.AddScoped<CastleWindsorJobActivator.ScopeDisposable>()
                .AddSingleton<IJobActivator>(new CastleWindsorJobActivator(container));

            container.AddServices(builder.Services);
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Example function:**

```
public class Function1
    {
        public Function1(IScoped1 scoped1, IScoped2 scoped2, ISingleton1 singleton1, ISingleton2 singleton2)
        {
            
        }

        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            string name = req.Query["name"];

            string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
            name = name ?? data?.name;

            return name != null
                ? (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult($"Hello, {name}")
                : new BadRequestObjectResult("Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body");
        }
    }
```

For now, this feature isn't officially released but you can follow other [dependency injection patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection#:%7E:text=%20Use%20dependency%20injection%20in%20.NET%20Azure%20Functions,instance%20of...%206%20Next%20steps.%20%20More%20). You can raise a feature request from Microsoft QnA or from Azure Portal.